# kendo ui chart template with value

Tags: templates, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I’m creating a stacked and grouped bar chart similar to the example you have in you demo’s… I’m populating it from remote data using JSON and .DataSource…

I’m trying to use .Tooltip.Template() to format the tooltip but want to include the value for each segment of the stacked bar within the tooltip… (so the tool tip says something like “Trucks, District-1 45” (or 50 or 75 or what ever the value is of the stacked segment)…

I’ve used

.Template("#= series.stack #s, #= series.name #= value #")

and

.Template("#= series.stack #s, #= series.name #= series.column #")

They work if I don’t add "#= value" or "#= series.column" but if I add it the code bombs…

I'm using VS2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you have invalid template

```
.Template("#= series.stack #s, #= series.name #= series.column #")
```

Probably you want to try something like:

```
.Template("#= series.stack #s, #= series.name # #= series.column #")
```

Comment: Thanks... the answer wasn't exactly correct but it certainly put me on the right track... thanks... final was to use: .Template("#= series.stack #s, #= series.name # #= value #")

Comment: Related... Now with the above answer I'm trying to format the "value"... I'm trying variations using kendo.format within the template.. i.e.  .Template("#=series.name #= kendo.Format('{0:0.000}',value) #") but get a similar error as my original post...

Comment: "#=series.name # #= kendo.toString(value,'0%') #" was the answer for this... I don't understand the requirement for the additional # though... Oh well...